# Android ImageView is shrinking if I start it offscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am animating an ImageView to mirror the functionality in an iOS app of the sun rising.  If I start it below the container RelativeLayout, it shrinks my ImageView height to the difference between the marginTop and the bottom of the RelativeView (in this case the image appears 100dp instead of 290).  It shows that in behavior in the preview as well as on the device.  Also it's not clipping the image to the relative layout.  How can I better animate this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_back_morning"
    android:id="@+id/rlTop"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:minHeight="290dp"
        android:minWidth="290dp"    
        android:src="@drawable/sun"
        android:id="@+id/ivSun"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:cropToPadding="true">    
</RelativeLayout>

//Fragment:
    TranslateAnimation translation;
    translation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0F, 0f, -250f);
    translation.setStartOffset(1000);
    translation.setDuration(1000);
    translation.setFillAfter(true);
    translation.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    ivSun.startAnimation(translation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine in emulator.
But try again changing your RelativeLayout to FrameLayout like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@drawable/home_back_morning"
    android:clipChildren="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSun"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:minHeight="290dp"
        android:minWidth="290dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/sun"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ahh, that will work but there's a lot more stuff in the layout, I only posted the relevant code, I'll have to do some rearranging.